# Migrating Web Form to MVC - VIewModel from stored procedures

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have been tasked with migrating an ASP>NET Web form website to ASP>NET MVC project. The reason are two fold. The site needs updating but it is also is a means of learning MVC.

The Web Forms application has as SQL backend and uses stored procedures extensively. Therefore we will not be using the code first MVC model, but creating the model from already existing tables.

My question is, should we be using the stored procedure that have already been created for the Web form project to create ViewModel files or is it advisable to just import the tables and then create new ViewModels manually as required?

I believe there is a tool called automapper that greatly reduces the time to manually create ViewModels but is it creating more work than necessary when the stored procedures have already been created?

Comment: You could look into Entity Framework, but stored procedures will give you the best performance. Are you going to build up your models in the controllers?

Comment: Entity framework supports stored procedures. It will create a .NET class to represent the fields returned by the procedure (if it returns rows). So that gives you your model. Then you may need ViewModels to provide the data needed for each specific view. AutoMapper helps you automatically translate between different types (e.g. between a model class and a viewmodel class, in your case), but it doesn't help you create them. It just saves a lot of manual code mapping properties to each other.

Comment: Or you can just use good old ADO.NET to call your procedures and select out the values into a class, like you would have done in a forms project. Maybe that class is usable as a viewmodel, maybe not. So you probably would still need viewmodels and could use automapper for translation between each type.

Comment: Firstly you can use your existing `stored procedures` into your MVC application. You have to use `Entity Framework` database first approach. into this your all entities and view model automatically mapped into your application

Comment: You can combine AutoMapper with Entity Framework Database First for stored procedure mappings and create viewmodel based from available table structures. All existing ASPX & ASCX pages can be reused for MVC environment, but this time remove any server controls + code behinds then rewrite them using HTML helpers.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. Sorry I should have mentioned that I have used entity framework to import the tables. I have since  tried the stored procedures I had a lot of error messages about adding id for a primary key. I think I am leaning towards using ADO.NET to call the stored procedures that will create classes then I can then call those classes in the controllers. This feels more like a baby steps/simplistic approach to learning MVC. Thanks to ADyson for the suggestion, and to all others for replying the advise was very helpful.